# Get field value out of submitted form passed in functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code to submit a form

```
<form class="sh-form"  onsubmit="validateCmntForm(this);">
```

and when I try to get field value from submitted form with following code it return `f.getElementById not a function` error

```
validateCmntForm(f){
 let nameField = f.getElementById('sh-cmnt-fullname');
 console.log(nameField)
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ? can someone help me with this ?

Update : reason for passing the form with this in function is that I have multiple same type of forms on page so can not use id with this and have to get field values from submitted form

Comment: The `getElementById` method is only available on the `document` object, not on e.g. a `form`.

Answer (score 2):

You could either reference the submit event directly (`target` will be an array of the attached children), or you could reference the input by ID if you would prefer. I've included a snippet below demonstrating both.

```js
function validateCmntForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target[0].value);
  console.log(document.getElementById('sh-cmnt-fullname').value);
}
```

```html
<form class="sh-form" onsubmit="validateCmntForm(event)">
  <input id="sh-cmnt-fullname" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use return validatecmntform

```js
function validateCmntForm(oForm){
console.log(oForm.elements["name"].value) // this is how you can get form data
return false;
}
```

```html
<form class="sh-form"  onsubmit="return validateCmntForm(this);">
<input type="text" name="name" id="myname">

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<form onsubmit='return validateCmntForm()' method='post' name='myForm'>
    <input type="text" name="eName">
</form>
```

in script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     validateCmntForm = function(){
        var eName = document.forms['myForm']['eName'].value;
        console.log(eName)
     }
</script>
```